# An irreducible chain with finitely many states is aperiodic if and only if there exists an n such that $p_{i,j}^{(n)}>0$, $\forall i,j \in S$

Tags: probability, markov-chains

> > An irreducible chain with finitely many states is aperiodic if and only if there exists an n such that $p_{i,j}^{(n)}>0$, $\forall i,j \in S$

I'm trying to prove this, I'm thinking about using this result:

> > If I is an aperiodic state then there exists $n_0$ such that $p_{ii}^{(n)}>0$, $\forall n\geq n_0$

But I'm a little confused, since the chain is aperiodic $d_i = 1$, and also, there exists $n_0$ such that $p_{ii}^{(n)}>0$, $\forall n\geq n_0$ by the last result.

But how can I infer that this $p_{i,j}^{(n)}>0$ ?

It's a little confused this topic, could someone help me please.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Remember a chain is irreducible iff, for every $i,j$, there exists $n=n(i,j)\geq 1$ such that $p_{i,j}^{(n)}>0$.

Now you need to make $n(i,j)$ independent of $i,j$ by aperiodicity.  But the chain is finite and we have $p_{i,j}^{(n+m)}\geq p_{i,i}^{(m)} p_{i,j}^{(n)}$, so for $n\geq n_0+\max_{i,j}n(i,j)$ we have ...

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with independent of i,j? Do you mean probabilistically ?

Comment: No, I mean the deterministic version.  The $n=n(i,j)$ in irreducibility depends on the states $i,j$, and now you need to make a choice of a fixed integer $n$ that works for all $i,j$ rather than allowing it to vary with $i,j$.